# Flutter hot restart leaves my keyboard up and can't navigate

Tags: flutter

new to flutter here.

When testing with some APIs I have some text input and when it doesn't work I get the errors and that renders my screen inactive. The screen freezes when I have the keyboard up, and then when I restart the keyboard remains up. The issue is that I have a bottom navigation board and have just started the app. I'm sure I could change the default initial locations, however this is something that has bothered me for a while. Does anyone know why this is?

**Screen freezes like this due to error**

[image: Screen freezes like this due to error]

**After hot restart screen**

[image: After hot restart screen]

I assumed that a hot restart would restart the keyboard position as well. Perhaps I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Hi I think it might be a bug as I have the same problem :)

Comment: This happens sometimes with hot reload. Just ignore it and instead of using hot reload just rerun your app again.

Comment: That sucks. having to rerun a bunch of times. I guess for testing purposes it'll be better to change my initial location.